# Increase font size up and down html tags

Tags: c#, html, font-size

I am trying to increase or decrease the displayed texts font.

but can only get it to increase once or decrease once then it stops working.

I am displaying text in web browesers and so i have to increase font size with html tags.

Could someone please direct me in what i'm doing wrong?

```
private void btnUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               
            HtmlFontPrev = "<font size='+1'>" + webPrevSQL.DocumentText + "</font>";
            webPrevSQL.DocumentText = HtmlFontPrev;
            HtmlFontPrev = "<font size='+1'>" + webCompareSQL.DocumentText + "</font>";
            webCompareSQL.DocumentText = HtmlFontPrev;
        }

        private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HtmlFontPrev = "<font size='-1'>" + webPrevSQL.DocumentText + "</font>";
            webPrevSQL.DocumentText = HtmlFontPrev;
            HtmlFontPrev = "<font size='-1'>" + webCompareSQL.DocumentText + "</font>";
            webCompareSQL.DocumentText = HtmlFontPrev;
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what's happening is that the font size is getting reset on each request (that's normal stateless HTTP behavior).  Try saving the increment value on each request by adding it to the session:

```
string currentFont = Session["currentFont"] ?? "0";
int intFont = int.Parse(currentFont) + 1;
Session["currentFont"] = intFont.ToString(); 

HtmlFontPrev = "<font size='+" + intFont + "'>" + webPrevSQL.DocumentText + "</font>";
webPrevSQL.DocumentText = HtmlFontPrev;
```

Comment: Im using win forms so cant use sessions, But i like the idea :D Will just swap out the session with a variable :D Thanks let me see if i can get it working :D

Comment: hmmmm not working, Once i change my font once i cant change it again? its like my web browser finalizes?

Comment: @Pommy Sorry, I just realized that misreading your question (thought it was a web app) led me to give a completely wrong answer.  The correct answer is: apparently you can't nest the *font size=+1* tags.  Can you try storing a variable and using *font size=+2*, then +3, etc?  I confirmed that does work (at least in Chrome).

Comment: Hey i just look at what i'm doing and see and obvious, Im changeing the text to add the tag font size, but when i click my button again the new tag will just be added again so my String would look something like this if i pushed the button 3 times.  <font size='5'><font size='4'><font size='3'>Bla bla</font></font></font> Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: No, I think the output would look like this, no?  Because you're adding a constant string, there's no variable there.  *<font size='+1'><font size='+1'>Bla bla</font></font>*  In any case, the nested *font* tags don't work.  The innermost tag is the one that takes effect.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, iv got it working just need to make some tweeks to make sure my size is never out of the range 1-7 :) thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Font size "+1" or "-1" is not valid font sizes.

Font size should be a number between 1-7.

Comment: +1 and -1 works but only once. when i click my button the font does change?

Comment: Works or not, iit's not good. And the font tag is deprecated, use css. I suggest you solve this on the client, with javascript, instead. Or just tell the user that their browser has builtin support for scaling text ;)

Comment: +1 and -1 [are valid font sizes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#edef-FONT): *A relative increase in font size. The value "+1" means one size larger. The value "-3" means three sizes smaller. All sizes belong to the scale of 1 to 7.*

Comment: Yes, my bad. Did not know about relative-size.